# Not able to print the array once new item added using push method

Tags: javascript, html

I am new to JavaScript. below is my code to print array once new item is added but not printing the array. can someone help. below is my code. I am also not getting any error in console. I have used push method to add new item to array and once added calling display function to print the array.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>
<input type="text" id="item" >
<br>
<br/>
<input type="button" value="Push" onClick="Push()">
&nbsp;
<input type="button" value="Pop" onClick="Pop()">
&nbsp;
<input type="button" value="Shift" onClick="Shift()">
&nbsp;
<input type="button" value="UnShift" onClick="UnShift()">
<div id="list_items"> </div>
<script type="text/javascript">

var arra1=[12,34,56,67,78,89,87];

function display()
{

var lists=document.getElementById('list_items');

document.write("Array items are:<br>" );

for(var i=0;i<arra1.length;i++)
{

var para = document.createElement('div');



lists.appendChild(para);
para.innerHTML = arra1[i];
}

}

function Push() 

{


var item1=document.getElementById("item").value;


arra1.push(item1);

display();  

}

function Pop()  
{

arra1.pop();

display();  

}




    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: below is my code:

Comment: Welcome to SO. What have you tried to achieve your wanted results? What has your research concerning your problem shown? Can you provide the code of your tries? https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask, How much research effort is expected https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users and How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve might be helpful to improve your question.

Comment: below is html:

<body>
<input type="text" id="item" >
<br>
<br/>
<input type="button" value="Push" onClick="Push()">
&nbsp;
<input type="button" value="Pop" onClick="Pop()">
&nbsp;
<input type="button" value="Shift" onClick="Shift()">
&nbsp;
<input type="button" value="UnShift" onClick="UnShift()">
<div id="list_items"> </div>
</body

Comment: Hi @Gunjan, it would be better if you edited your question to include the HTML you just commented.

Comment: Hi Sean just updated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I just Edited this a little bit and got it working.

```js
var arra1=[12,34,56,67,78,89,87];

function display()
{

var lists=document.getElementById('list_items');

for(var i=0;i<arra1.length;i++)
{

var para = document.createElement('p');
lists.appendChild(para);
para.innerHTML = arra1[i];
}

}

function Push() 

{


var item1=document.getElementById("item").value;


arra1.push(item1);

display();  

}

function Pop()  
{

arra1.pop();

display();  

}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>
<input type="text" id="item" >
<br>
<br/>
<input type="button" value="Push" onClick="Push()">
&nbsp;
<input type="button" value="Pop" onClick="Pop()">
&nbsp;
<input type="button" value="Shift" onClick="Shift()">
&nbsp;
<input type="button" value="UnShift" onClick="UnShift()">
<div id="list_items"> 

</div>
<scrip

    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: what was the error? i see you used p instead of div

Comment: You was removing the input and then rendering the list I modified the code to render the things properly.
There was no error. The code is correct you just needed to call the display function without the document.write. The document.write function was removing whatever there was previously and just writing the passed string in it.

Comment: If my answer suits what you wanted then can you please mark it as answer?